# Groovy unit test for overloaded method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, mocking

Using the MockFor how can I write unit tests for overloaded methods.

For example

```
public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request, HttpContext context)
```

and

```
public HttpResponse execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)
```

I have written:

```
        def responseMocker = new MockFor(HttpResponse.class)
        HttpResponse response = responseMocker.proxyInstance()
        def requestMocker = new MockFor(HttpUriRequest.class)
        def request = requestMocker.proxyInstance()
        def contextMocker = new MockFor(HttpContext.class)
        def context = contextMocker.proxyInstance();
        def clientMocker = new MockFor(HttpClient.class)
        clientMocker.demand.execute(request, context) { response }

        HttpClientSample client = new HttpClientSample(clientMocker.proxyInstance())

        assertEquals response, client.execute(request,context)
```

This test above fails with:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the demanded methods like this:

```
mock.demand.execute { HttpUriRequest request, HttpContext context -> ... }
mock.demand.execute { HttpHost target, HttpRequest request -> ... }
```

this will bind the demanded methods to the appropriate overloaded method signatures.

Comment: I know I shouldn't use a comment to say thanks, but cheers fella!

Comment: But how do you demand it gets executed without replacing the method body?  I still want the original method to be called.